# Including CTE within a query

Tags: sql

I have the following code which works perfectly.

What I need to do is include it in a query using the result of the CTE as a column in the query result but I cannot work out the way to include it.
Any ideas please?

What I would like is effectively this:

```
select a, 
b, 
c, 
d,

WITH invoicedates AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Inv_Date DESC) AS RowNumber,
        inv_Date, INVIT_PARTNO
    FROM Invoices join InvoiceItems on invit_invno = inv_no
    WHERE invit_partno  = stock_no and inv_canind <> 'Y' and inv_date >= DATEADD(yy, -1, getdate())
)
SELECT
   AVG(DATEDIFF(DD, O2.Inv_Date, O1.Inv_Date)) AS AverageFrequency
FROM invoicedates O1
LEFT JOIN invoicedates O2
    ON O2.RowNumber = O1.RowNumber + 1
```

from stock where ..........

to give a resulting output of a b c d result

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just reorder how you're using the CTE:

```
    ; WITH invoicedates (RowNumber, inv_Date, INVIT_PARTNO) AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Inv_Date DESC) AS RowNumber,
        inv_Date, INVIT_PARTNO
    FROM Invoices join InvoiceItems on invit_invno = inv_no
    WHERE invit_partno  = stock_no and inv_canind <> 'Y' and inv_date >= DATEADD(yy, -1, getdate())
)

select a, 
b, 
c, 
d,
  AVG(DATEDIFF(DD, O2.Inv_Date, O1.Inv_Date)) AS AverageFrequency
FROM invoicedates O1
LEFT JOIN invoicedates O2
    ON O2.RowNumber = O1.RowNumber + 1
```

Comment: Yes... but `AVG()` is an aggregate function, so he'll need a `GROUP BY` for the other columns.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you!  I'm forever having to go back and add my GROUP BYs.

Comment: Thank you very much - just perfect. I did not realise that I could split it like that.